# I cannot bring the Blazorise Live-Chart component working. I get Error with the related script files when opening page in the browser

Tags: chart.js, razor-pages, blazor-server-side, blazorise

I have Blazor server side app where I want to add a Blazorise live Chart component.
https://blazorise.com/docs/extensions/chart-live

I have added all neccasary packages to my project and also the sample code like below.
I get no Error during building and publishing.

But I get Error with the related script files when I open the page in my browser. As my server has no internet acces I have downloaded the neccesary files under the wwroot directory of my project. But I got for all of them the Error that they are not recognised. What could be the problem?
The only thing that is strange for me, is that the script files have no extensions???

Here the related part in my host_cshtml file

```
<script src="files/luxon"></script>
<script src="files/chartjs-adapter-luxon"></script>
<script src="files/chartjs-plugin-streaming"></script>
```

Here the errors that I get from the browser for the three script files.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'luxon:2
Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'chartjs-adapter-luxon:2
Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'chartjs-plugin-streaming:2
```

Here my razor file

```
<LineChart @ref="horizontalLineChart" TItem="LiveDataPoint" OptionsObject="@horizontalLineChartOptions">
<ChartStreaming TItem="LiveDataPoint"
                Options="new ChartStreamingOptions { Delay = 2000 }"
                Refreshed="@OnHorizontalLineRefreshed" />
</LineChart>

@code{
LineChart<LiveDataPoint> horizontalLineChart;
Random random = new Random( DateTime.Now.Millisecond );

string[] Labels = { "Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange" };
List<string> backgroundColors = new List<string> { ChartColor.FromRgba( 255, 99, 132, 0.2f ), ChartColor.FromRgba( 54, 162, 235, 0.2f ), ChartColor.FromRgba( 255, 206, 86, 0.2f ), ChartColor.FromRgba( 75, 192, 192, 0.2f ), ChartColor.FromRgba( 153, 102, 255, 0.2f ), ChartColor.FromRgba( 255, 159, 64, 0.2f ) };
List<string> borderColors = new List<string> { ChartColor.FromRgba( 255, 99, 132, 1f ), ChartColor.FromRgba( 54, 162, 235, 1f ), ChartColor.FromRgba( 255, 206, 86, 1f ), ChartColor.FromRgba( 75, 192, 192, 1f ), ChartColor.FromRgba( 153, 102, 255, 1f ), ChartColor.FromRgba( 255, 159, 64, 1f ) };

public struct LiveDataPoint
{
    public object X { get; set; }

    public object Y { get; set; }
}

object horizontalLineChartOptions = new
{
    Scales = new
    {
        Y = new
        {
            Title = new
            {
                Display = true,
                Text = "Value"
            }
        }
    },
    Interaction = new
    {
        intersect = false
    }
};

protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync( bool firstRender )
{
    if ( firstRender )
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(
            HandleRedraw( horizontalLineChart, GetLineChartDataset1 ) );
    }
}

async Task HandleRedraw<TDataSet, TItem, TOptions, TModel>( BaseChart<TDataSet, TItem, TOptions, TModel> chart, params Func<TDataSet>[] getDataSets )
    where TDataSet : ChartDataset<TItem>
    where TOptions : ChartOptions
    where TModel : ChartModel
{
    await chart.Clear();

    await chart.AddLabelsDatasetsAndUpdate( Labels, getDataSets.Select( x => x.Invoke() ).ToArray() );
}

LineChartDataset<LiveDataPoint> GetLineChartDataset1()
{
    return new LineChartDataset<LiveDataPoint>
    {
        Data = new List<LiveDataPoint>(),
        Label = "Dataset 1 (linear interpolation)",
        BackgroundColor = backgroundColors[0],
        BorderColor = borderColors[0],
        Fill = false,
        Tension = 0,
        BorderDash = new List<int> { 8, 4 },
    };
}

Task OnHorizontalLineRefreshed( ChartStreamingData<LiveDataPoint> data )
{
    data.Value = new LiveDataPoint
    {
        X = DateTime.Now,
        Y = RandomScalingFactor(),
    };

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

double RandomScalingFactor()
{
    return ( random.NextDouble() > 0.5 ? 1.0 : -1.0 ) * Math.Round( random.NextDouble() * 100 );
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have added .js extensions to the files and it worked